# System.AggregateException: One or more errors ocurred. (A task was canceled.)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, task

I'm trying to call LoadPickerData method to load the result in a Picker using async/await from the a ViewModel. I get the following error:
[image]

**Error**

```
System.AggregateException
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2027 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:496 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:466 
  at EmployeeApp.Helpers.ConnectivityHelper.CheckConnectivity () [0x00049] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\Helpers\ConnectivityHelper.cs:34 
  at EmployeeApp.Helpers.ConnectivityHelper.get_IsConnected () [0x00000] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\Helpers\ConnectivityHelper.cs:21 
  at EmployeeApp.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.get_ServiceAreaStore () [0x00000] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs:27 
  at EmployeeApp.ViewModels.MailboxViewModel.GetPickerServiceArea () [0x0000f] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\ViewModels\MailboxViewModel.cs:60 
  at EmployeeApp.MailboxPage.LoadPickerData () [0x0002b] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\Views\MailBoxPage.xaml.cs:70 
  at EmployeeApp.MailboxPage.OnAppearing () [0x0002c] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\Views\MailBoxPage.xaml.cs:31 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021 
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <06692e0cad5848598a0f46942a89e99f>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <06692e0cad5848598a0f46942a89e99f>:0 
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <06692e0cad5848598a0f46942a89e99f>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.44(intptr,intptr)
```

I'm trying to load the result of a GET request in a picker, but when I start the app the first time, it does not and I get the previous exception and the second time I run it I no longer get that error.
I looked for why and I was making the call of an asynchronous method in a constructor and that is bad code, I changed it to an OnAppearing () method but still that exception keeps coming out and I don't have idea the why yet

MailboxPage.xaml.cs

```
public MailboxPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new MailboxViewModel();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await LoadPickerData();
    }

private async Task<IEnumerable<ServiceArea>> LoadPickerData()
    {
        var vm = new MailboxViewModel();

        var servicesareas = await vm.GetPickerServiceArea();
        try
        {
            ServiceAreaPicker.ItemsSource = servicesareas.ToList();
            ServiceAreaPicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Name");
        }
        catch(AggregateException ae)
        {
            foreach (var e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().FullName} { e.Message}");
            }
        }

        return servicesareas;
    }
```

MailboxViewModel.cs

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ServiceArea>> GetPickerServiceArea()
    {
        try
        {
            PickerItems = await ServiceAreaStore.GetPickerItemsAsync(true);
            foreach (var item in PickerItems)
                Items.Add(item);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            foreach (var e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().FullName} { e.Message}");
            }
        }

        return PickerItems;
    }
```

ServiceAreaStoreAPI.cs

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ServiceArea>> GetPickerItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (forceRefresh)
        {
            var json = await Client.GetStringAsync($"api/servicearea");
            Servicesareas = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ServiceArea>>(json));
            try
            {
                var success = LocalDatabase.AddItemsAsync(Servicesareas);
                if (!success.Result)
                {
                    //Log de fallo en la insercion de datos.
                }
            }
            catch(AggregateException ae)
            {
               foreach (var e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
               {
                  Debug.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().FullName} { e.Message}");
               }
            }
        }
        return Servicesareas;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the `EmployeeApp.Helpers.ConnectivityHelper.CheckConnectivity` method? It looks like the error is being thrown on line 34 of that file: `EmployeeApp.Helpers.ConnectivityHelper.CheckConnectivity () [0x00049] in F:\Workspace\BajaDev\MPA\_Project\EmployeeApp\Helpers\ConnectivityHelper.cs:34 `

Comment: @Andrew Yeah sure, but it's just a status

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/5MpLBq)

Comment: @Andrew you can see it?

Comment: @Andrew Line 34: `var json = client.GetStringAsync($"api/status").Result;`

Comment: `.Result` will block the UI thread which you typically want to avoid at startup. I would recommend confirming that is the line throwing error so you can narrow down your troubleshooting.

Comment: @Andrew yes, it is, but I don't know how to change 'cause I didn't do that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ServiceAreaStoreAPI`, you don't await a task which might be causing your issue since it'll continue on and return a canceled result.

`var success = LocalDatabase.AddItemsAsync(Servicesareas);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the Task.Wait() method in the method body, then adding the **async** keyword to the method will fix this issue. Ex:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id) { }
```